# What technologies/protocols does Postgres DBlink use?

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I am using Postgres DBlink (using SSL), but I have no idea of how it is implemented in Postgres.

My question is, what protocols/technologies does Postgres DBlink use?

Like websockets? http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dblink uses a standard libpq connection under the hood. The same that is used in any postgres client. It's not websocket, it's not http.

It's a custom, Postgres specific binary protocol.

If you want more details then read this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on a glance at the [implementation](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/322548a8abe225f2cfd6a48e07b99e2711d28ef7/contrib/dblink) of `dblink`, it is using a regular Postgres database [connection](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html), which is of the type `PGconn`.

So the technologies and [protocols](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/protocol.html) used depend on the connection string you provide to the function. For example, if you provide the parameters necessary to connect with SSL, then it will attempt to use SSL.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the duplicate answer. We must have been answering at the same time.